# Algorithm Basics

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

What does "n" or "N" in asymptotic notation actually means?
It is usually stated that the "n" is the size of the input.
Does it mean that it is the size of the algorithm,that it the size of the whole chunk of algorithm,meaning if a algorithm has 20 lines it's "n" is more than a algorithm which have 10 lines.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Your question is a very basic one. Let me direct you towards our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599) which cover some fundamentals you seem to be missing in detail. Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific problems you encountered. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The exact value of $n$ depends on the context. Most of the time $n$ is the length of the input in bits or in machine words. Note that the length of a number $x$ in bits is roughly $\log x$, since this is how many bits you need to encode $x$.

Answer (score 3):

No, $n$ is, as you say, the size of the *input* – the data you're working on. Nothing to do with the size of the algorithm – the thing that does the work.

So, for example, if your algorithm adds numbers, the input is the numbers you want to add and the length of the input is the number of characters (bits, decimal digits, whatever format you're using) required to express the input.

Answer (score 0):

Usually $n$ relates an asymptotic order of your algorithm. So, if an algorithm is said to be in $O(n)$, it means it can work in a linear time. This linear time can be simply explained as time taken to read a 1-D array. There are more orders like $ n^2$ ( where the algorithm takes $n^2$ time upon working with an $n$-sized input, preferably an array or so ), $nlogn$, $2^n$, etc.
For example, if you write up an algorithm like

```
Algo_Add(Array a[],Size n)
{
    variable sum : integer
    variable i = 1 : integer
    loop while i <= n
    {
        sum = sum + a[i]
    }
    return sum
}
```

Here, the algorithm traverses the array $a[ ]$  in a linear time $n$.
But if the algorithm would have been like

```
Algo_Add(Array a[],Size n)
    {
        variable sum : integer
        variable i = 1 : integer
        loop while i <= n
        {
             variable j = 1 : integer
             variable sum2 : integer
             loop while j <= n
             {
                 sum2 = sum2 + a[j]
             }
             sum = sum + sum2
        }
        return sum
    }
```

Here, the algorithm traverses the array $a[]$ in a linear time too. But the difference here is that for every element $a[i]$ we get while traversing the array $a[]$, we traverse the array in a linear time of $O(n)$ again. So for $n$ elements, we actually traverse the array $n^2$ number of times. So the second algorithm is of order $O(n^2)$.Hope this helps you.

Comment: "Usually $n$ relates an asymptotic order of your algorithm." I have no idea what that means. $n$ is, quite simply, the length of the input.

Comment: An algorithm of O(n) doesn't mean it is the input size n. Rather, it means the time required by the algorithm to process a size n input in a time of c*n +d where c,d are  real numbers.
if an  algorithm is O(n^2), it means the algorithm takes time c*n^2 +d*n + e ( may include a logarithmic value f*log(n) or so , but not c*n*log(n) )  for an input of size n where c,d,e,f are real numbers.